# Unable to override magento Onepage Controller

Tags: magento, overriding, frontend, controllers

Hi all I am trying to override Magento's checkout OnepageController its working on my local machine but when I Upload the same code to my server its not.

Here is my app/etc/modules/Kushagra_Checkout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kushagra_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Kushagra_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Kushagra/Checkout/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kushagra_Checkout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Kushagra_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Kushagra_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Kushagra_Checkout</Kushagra_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and app/code/local/Kushagra/Checkout/OnepageController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Kushagra_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController  {
     public function failureAction()
        {
            echo "hi there";exit;
            $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'payment_failed',
                array('order' => $order)
            );
            parent::failureAction();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Can anyone please let me know what I may be doing wrong

Comment: did u check for other module's conflict?

Comment: No I haven't done that, I will check that thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a module conflict issue